# How to copy a red black tree to another rb tree and remove the old one?

Tags: c

I want to copy nodes in an RB tree that satisfy a condition into another RB tree and remove the old one.

I've made these functions:

```c
void copy_tree(node* old_root, node** copied_root) {
    if(old_root != NULL) {
        if(condition(old_root->key) == true) {
            *copied_root = insert(*copied_root, old_root);
        }

        copy_tree(old_root->left, copied_root);
        copy_tree(old_root->right, copied_root);
    }
}

node* copy_and_destroy(node* old_root) {
    node* copied_root = NULL;

    copy_tree(old_root, &copied_root);

    destroy(old_root);
    return copied_root;
}
```

Then, in another function, I call them:

```c
tree = copy_and_destroy(tree);
```

I know that the `condition`, `destroy`, and `insert` functions are correct. But it gives me a **segmentation fault**. So, are these 2 functions correct?

Comment: Consoder providing a [mcve].

Comment: Your debugger is your friend. Invest 30 minutes to learn the basics of your debugger.

Comment: I wonder why you need this. Instead of creating a new tree and deleting the old tree, why not just use the old tree?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. because in an rb-tree, insertion and deletion cost the same, so if I have to delete most of the nodes it's better to create another tree and throw away the old one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the source to your `rb_insert` function, I suspect that it is adding the node pointed to by the second parameter to the new tree without copying the node. That would lead to problems while the old tree is still being traversed.

You need to remove the node from the old tree before moving it to  the new tree.

If copying (rather than moving) nodes from the the old tree to the new tree, you need to create a copy of the node and add the copy to the new tree.